# why promise returns an unexpected output for nested promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have code below and based on MDN document, I know how `result` and `state` will be specified for a `promise`, resulted from a handler:

> returns a value: p gets fulfilled with the returned value as its
> value.

> doesn't return anything: p gets fulfilled with undefined as its
> value.

> throws an error: p gets rejected with the thrown error as its
> value.

> returns an already fulfilled promise: p gets fulfilled with
> that promise's value as its value.

> returns an already rejected promise: p gets rejected with that promise's  > value as its value.

> returns another pending promise: p is pending and becomes
> fulfilled/rejected with that promise's value as its value immediately
> after that promise becomes fulfilled/rejected.

so why the `state` for my `promise` is `fullfilled`?

code:

```
const test = Promise.reject(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
throw new Error("error")
}))

const test2 = test.catch((result) => {
result.catch(() => {
    throw new Error("error2");
})
})

console.log(test2);

//result in console:
//[[Prototype]]: Promise
//[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
//[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the inner promise:

```js
const test = Promise.reject(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
throw new Error("error")
}))

const test2 = test.catch((result) => {
  return result.catch(() => {
    throw new Error("error2");
})
})

console.log(test2);
```

[image]

Comment: so basically it's a typo?@alexanderNenashev

Comment: @lome1446 not sure, you didn't mistype `return` you just missed it for some reason, maybe you didn't pay attention or know that it was required. so decide yourself